# How to use grep with two patterns?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line

I have followed many links and reference documentation but still facing errors.
I want to list all the words start or ending with 'sx'.
I already found a solution which works fine:

```
awk '/^sx|sx$/' usr/dict/words
```

However I tried to use grep or egrep and neither worked.
And then I made it simpler. Any word which contains 'ax' or 'sx', and again it did not work!

```
grep 'ax|sx' words
grep -E '^ax\|sx$' words
egrep '^ax\|sx$' words
```

Error:

```
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There's little to help here unless you upgrade your version of `grep`.  Alternatively, use other tools.

Comment: @devnull It seems you are wrong! Because the problem has been solved.

Comment: I fail to understand how the same thing as mentioned in the accepted answer did not work for you earlier!  `egrep '^ax|sx$' words`

Comment: @devnull because there were no grouping. With parentheses it worked fine.

Comment: @devnull I have added your answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
egrep '(^ax|sx$)' usr/dict/words
```

**NOTE:**
I couldn't find any words ending in `sx` on the dictionary I've [used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt).

Comment: Yes it's working. Can you explain a bit the difference. I have read the documentation and there is no parentheses.

Comment: You are right. There is no word with sx. I just used it as example but with ax it is working.

Comment: Your code was right, it only missed the group (), so it can match `^ax` or `sx$`.