# Bash grep command starts with or ends with

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, grep

I'm after a command that will return results based on a pattern match that starts with or ends with a the given pattern.

This is what i have so far.

```
"cat input.txt | grep "^in|in$"
```

My main problem is that i cant get the (or) to work but i can get them to work individually.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks like it was your friend who asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269690/how-to-use-grep-with-two-patterns/) a while back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
grep "^in\|in$" input.txt
```

by default, grep use `BRE`, you have to escape the `|`. Or use grep's `-E or -P`, in order to avoid escaping those char with special meaning.

P.S, the `cat` is no necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '/^start|end$/' file
```

It will print all lines starting with `start` or ending with `end`

```
cat file
nothing
start with this
or it does have an end
or the end is near
```

```
awk '/^start|end$/' file
start with this
or it does have an end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using egrep rather than grep? Using the following should work for what you're after:

```
egrep "^in|in$" input.txt
```

There's no need to have the cat at the start, the above will work fine.